# How do I get a Panasonic KX-FLB 802 multi function printer working?

Tags: printing

I am unable to make the PANASONIC KX-FLB 802 attached to the pc work.

Any suggestions ? Searching for the it in the Printers tool results in "No matches found"

Comment: What happens when you use "printers" to search for it?

Comment: It says 'no matches found'!